# Google Maps API + KML Files

Tags: php, google-maps, kml

I'm building a google map that i'd like to display various things from tables within my mysql database.

I've been looking at going down the KML route, and so far so good, to an extent.

i've got a KML file generating from all the rows in the table i'm currently targeting, but my question is, can i get them into 'categorys' based on a row in the database?

my code as it is now is below:

```
<?php
require('dblogin.php');

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server.
$connection = mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) 
{
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Sets the active MySQL database.
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) 
{
 die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Selects all the rows in the markers table.
$query = 'SELECT * FROM directory WHERE 1';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) 
{
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Creates an array of strings to hold the lines of the KML file.
$kml = array('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
$kml[] = '<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">';
$kml[] = ' <Document>';
$kml[] = ' <Style id="restaurantStyle">';
$kml[] = ' <IconStyle id="restuarantIcon">';
$kml[] = ' <Icon>';
$kml[] = ' <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon63.png</href>';
$kml[] = ' </Icon>';
$kml[] = ' </IconStyle>';
$kml[] = ' </Style>';
$kml[] = ' <Style id="barStyle">';
$kml[] = ' <IconStyle id="barIcon">';
$kml[] = ' <Icon>';
$kml[] = ' <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon27.png</href>';
$kml[] = ' </Icon>';
$kml[] = ' </IconStyle>';
$kml[] = ' </Style>';

// Iterates through the rows, printing a node for each row.
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
$kml[] = ' <Placemark id="placemark' . $row['id'] . '">';
$kml[] = ' <name>' . htmlentities($row['name']) . '</name>';
$kml[] = ' <description>' . htmlentities($row['coverage']) . '</description>';
$kml[] = ' <styleUrl>#' . ($row['category']) .'Style</styleUrl>';
$kml[] = ' <Point>';
$kml[] = ' <coordinates>' . $row['lon'] . ','  . $row['lat'] . '</coordinates>';
$kml[] = ' </Point>';
$kml[] = ' </Placemark>';

} 

// End XML file
$kml[] = ' </Document>';
$kml[] = '</kml>';
$kmlOutput = join("\n", $kml);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.kml"');
echo $kmlOutput;
?>
```

which outputs a kml file which can be read via google maps: https://www.google.com/maps?sll=37.062437029501915%2C-95.7995588577611&sspn=72.35087833291526%2C95.41055226527986&t=m&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google-boost.co.uk%2Fmapsearch%2Ffile.kml&output=classic&dg=opt

what i want to do is to 'sort' the results somewhat, so that on the left hand side we have all business sorted into categorys based on what the category row in the database is.

i.e. have all plumbers grouped together, all removal companies grouped together etc.

Have started playing around with the KML route this morning and got this far, if anyone can shed any further light on adding some structure it'd certainly make my day alot better!

Comment: Your KML URL doesn't work for me on Google Maps, it reports `http://www.google-boost.co.... could not be displayed because it is not a valid KML or KMZ file.`.  The KML feed validator agrees that it isn't valid: http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google-boost.co.uk%2Fmapsearch%2Ffile.kml (main problem being `</folder>` should be `</Folder>`, xml is case sensitive).

Comment: ah, i was playing around with the php, after looking at a mapsample kml i found from google i saw that they seem to be wrapped in <folder> tags to categorize them somewhat? my objective is to group all the categories together so that the tree would display 

| Category
|---Company
| 
| Category 2
|---Company 
|---Company 

etc?

Comment: Another thing to consider is semantic vs. visual categorization. You can have a flat-structured KML file that still renders the data by categories if you make more use of the 'style' tag (which i see you're already including) to give each category its own pin colour, for example. Likewise, a well-structured KML can render without its categories if you DON'T style each one differently. Consider having your generator do this: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#custom_styles